# SSH Tunneling with Python

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-tunnel

my goal is to update Host3 buried as follows:
[Internet]<---->[Host1:HasInternet]<---->[Host2:Locked-by-VPN]<---->[Host3:No-Internet]

Currently, I have to run a series of SSH commands to first build Reverse SSH connections from Host1 to Host2 to Host3 followed by Dynamic Tunnels to then update my Host3 as follows (see screenshot of table):

[image]

I want to automate this series of SSH tunnels with python. I have looked into paramiko, an the sshtunnels libraries and I'm not seeing how to use them to my goal.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does `ssh -J <username>@Locked-By-VPN <username>@Has-No-Internet` work? I don't think you need to manage all these tunnels manually.

Comment: Wow, just wow. Thank you from the bottom of my heart. I did not realize the -j switch was even a thing. Praise be to Alan Turing Almighty. Praise be.

Comment: You might also want to check `ProxyJump` in `man ssh_config` (for specifying the same information from your config file, rather than on the command line), and the `ProxyCommand` in case you need slightly more control over the connection process.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than managing the tunnels manually, let `ssh` do it for you with the `ProxyJump` option, which you can access with `-J` on the command line.

```
ssh -J <username>@Locked-By-VPN <username>@Has-No-Internet
```

This establishes a connection to `Has-No-Internet` by first connecting to `Locked-By-VPN`.

You can abbreviate this by adding the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host Host3
   Hostname
   User <username>
   ProxyJump <username>@Locked-By-VPN
```

Then you can simply run `ssh Host3`; `ssh` will get the real host name, the necessary user name, and the intermediate host from the configuration file.

There is also a `ProxyCommand` option you can use to provide more control over the connection process. See `man ssh_config` for more details on both options.